# How to send focus from card to home after onClick

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have an `Activity` that accepts voice input, instantiates a `Card` and then responds to an `onClick` event. When the `onClick` fires off, I want redirect the use back to the "OK Glass" view or the timeline containing a historical card representing that action. I can't seem to find any obvious way to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a live card, you can call:

```
finish();
```

to return to the home screen (OK Glass).

I tested this on XE16 and it worked.

Here is some more detailed code from my Activity:

```
    @Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
        {
                //return to OK Glass screen
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

If you provide some code to make your question more specific I can provide more specific guidance.

Comment: You gave me exactly what I was looking for; is this in the guide anywhere?

Comment: It's an Android lifecycle thing, a guess on my part from past Android experience. Generally Glass behaves like Android, but there are exceptions, so I generally trust but verify like I did in this case.  Here is a reference for you: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html